# Java Apache set additional parameters in "Content-Disposition:"

Tags: java, http, content-disposition

I am using java Apache 5.3.1, I am trying to send a multipart with XML, and need the following "Content-Disposition:" set -

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"; filename="test.xml"
```

If I use this I get most if it -

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addPart("xml", new StringBody(xml, ContentType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

but that only produces

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"
```

How do I get it to add the  'filename="test.xml"' part?
Thanks

Comment: Java Apache what? Do you mean the HTTP Client?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use builder.addBinaryBody and it will add the filename.

```java
builder.addBinaryBody(
  "xml",
  xml.getBytes(),
  ContentType.APPLICATION_XML,"test.xlm");
```